# Interest rate volatility, structural breaks, and GARCH

Tags: variance, garch, structural-change

I'm trying to estimate the volatility of an interest rate over time using GARCH. A problem that I'm currently facing is that the interest rate shows strong signs of structural breaks, which leads to huge and short increases in volatility. This is confirmed by various tests for structural breaks (e.g. the Bai-Perron-Test).

Based on this observation I was thinking about three methods on how to deal with this problem and still arrive at a decent volatility estimate. These three methods are:

1. Estimate the structural break points and the corresponding mean values. Afterwards, I could construct a GARCH model for the deviations of the interest rate from the regime specific mean (i.e. the difference between the estimated mean and the original interest rate value for each period). This would be similar to using only the first difference for exchange rates that were originally non-stationary as an input for the GARCH model.
2. Using a specification of the GARCH model that already includes structural breaks in the mean. Unfortunately I'm unable to find any GARCH specifications that deal with this problem. Instead, most articles that I was able to find consider only regime changes in volatility and not in the mean, e.g. the article by [Edwards and Susmel](https://www.anderson.ucla.edu/faculty_pages/sebastian.edwards/interest-rate-volatility.pdf).
3. Splitting the time series into two or three sub-sections (e.g. based on the breakpoints determined using Bai-Perron) and performing GARCH separately for each section. In doing so, I could construct a time series for the volatility that consists of two or three sub-sections.

Based on these three "potential" methods I was wondering whether one of the three can be applied. If not, are there any other methods to estimate the volatility for interest rates with structural breaks? For example, is GARCH even the right model for this task or are other estimation techniques that should be preferred instead?

p.s. The third option was edited afterwards.

Thanks for your input.